# Is it possible to start the program on a non-static method?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm trying to start a project off with a non-static method, but every time, I'm getting an error message saying "Program does not contain a static "Main" method suitable for an entry point." so is there any way I can fix this and still start off with a non-static method?

Comment: You cant use a non-static method to start a program as it need to be initialized first.

Answer (score 6):

No. Entry points must be `static`. You can have your entry-point just `new` up some non-static type and execute an instance method of your choosing, though...

```cs
class P
{
    static void Main() => new P().Run();
    void Run() {...}
}
```

Comment: ok is there any way i can start on a static method then make that go to a non-static method? I've made some public strings basically and they'll only work on non-static methods but i need to make the static method go to the non static method

Comment: Yes, Mark showed you exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

No, because there is no state at the time a program is started. Hence, the only way to create that state is via a stateless, i.e. static, method.